# update a table in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to do an action after creating an event.
Create a control form that has been selected in form1 several p, and update a PSelected table.
I have two files, A.html and A.ts

A.html:

```
<mat-select placeholder="form1" [formControl]="product" (ngModelChange)="getP($event)" multiple> <mat-option *ngFor="let p of allProduct" [value]="p.pro_nom">{{p.pro_nom}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>

<mat-form-field *ngFor="let valeurControls of valeursControls">
   <input matInput maxLength="255" type="text [placeholder]="valeurControls.valeur.n [formControl]="valeurControls.formControl">
</mat-form-field>
```

A.ts:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { filter, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Product, Candy } from 'src/app/models';
import { Service } from 'src/app/services';
import { Listener } from 'selenium-webdriver';

@Component({
    selector: 'ei',
    templateUrl: './A.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./A.component.less'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AComponent extends FormFieldsContainer implements OnInit {

    @Output('change') inputChange = new EventEmitter();

    //var

    allProduct: Product[];
    Candy: Candy;

    // Form
    actionFormGroup: FormGroup;
    product: FormControl;
    event: Listener[]

    // P
    valeursControls: { valeur: candy, formControl: FormControl }[] = [];

    public pSelected: Array<any>;

    // Constructor
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        super();
        this.Candy = this.Candy ? this.Candy : { name: null, type: null };
        this.pSelected = [];
        this.buildForm();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.Service.getProduct()
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
            .subscribe(p => {
                this.allProduct = p;
            });
    }
    getP(event?: Event[]) {
        if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
            this.pSelected = [];
        } else {
            this.pSelected = event;
        }
        console.log(this.pSelected)
        return this.pSelected;
    }

    getFormGroup(): FormGroup {
        return this.actionFormGroup;
    }

    onSubmitSuccess<Boolean>(result: Boolean) {

    }

    private buildForm() {
        this.submitted = false;
        this.p= this.fb.control('', Validators.required);
        this.actionFormGroup = this.fb.group({
            product: this.product
        });

        // my array does not update, it remains empty
        this.pSelected .forEach(p => {
            const VarFormControl = this.fb.control(null);
            this.valeursControls.push({
                valeur: { name: p, type: this.Candy.type },
                formControl: VarFormControl 
            });
            this.actionFormGroup.addControl(p, VarFormControl );
        });
    }
    Actions() {
        this.submitted = true;
    }
}
```

in the function getP(), my table is updating, but when I use it in buildForm() it is empty yet it should have the same value

Comment: Start with using more descriptive variable names, not 'b' and 'p'. It's really hard to read your code like that.

Comment: I am really sorry

Comment: You can just edit your code here and use something more descriptive

Answer (score 1):

you are calling this.buildForm(); from the component constructor.
The value of pSelected will be the declared one: public pSelected: Array;

You should rebuild valeursControls any time you select/unselect a value inside the mat-select component.

try:

```
getP(event?: Event[]) {
    this.valeursControls = [];
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
        this.pSelected = [];
    } else {
        this.pSelected = event;
        this.buildValeursControls();
    }
}

private buildValeursControls(){
    this.pSelected.forEach(p => {
        const VarFormControl = this.fb.control(null);
        this.valeursControls.push({
            valeur: { n: p, r: this.B.r },
            formControl: VarFormControl 
        });
        this.actionFormGroup.addControl(p, VarFormControl );
    });
}

private buildForm() {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.p= this.fb.control('', Validators.required);
    this.actionFormGroup = this.fb.group({
        p: this.p
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you could alternatively use an observable as pSelected and buildForm in the subscribe()

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work very well. When I click it adds the form control, but if I click again, it does not remove it. So I'm left with duplicates

Comment: @NickLersberghe I do not know how to use observable in this context.

Comment: You make an observable from your pSelected. In your constructor, you subscribe to it. Whenever changes occur to pSelected, that subscription will run that code. That way, each time pSelected is changed, buildForm() will be called. Try something like 'pSelected: Observable<Array<any>>' and in your constructor 'this.pSelected.subscribe(arr => this.buildForm(arr))'. You can change that method to use that parameter instead of this.pSelected then. Be sure to test it, I'm not completely sure if that'll work as intended.